# How to detect GET parameters in URL, and place values according to that,?

Tags: javascript, php, url

I am working on a project in PHP and JavaScript, where i have to create a value from my end, and pass the same in URL query string on redirect from my URL, Below is Description: 
I have a URL, https://abc.amindfad.com/c.php?id={abdid}

on above URL I want redirection, and pass value from my end by detecting where is *{abdid}*

The above URL will be redirecting from (my URL) :-
https://console.adcashod.net/click.php

i have not done anything yet, Because i am little confused in Code which should be used here.

in Results I want that, when I click on 
(my URL) :-
https://console.adcashod.net/click.php

it get redirects to :-
https://abc.amindfad.com/c.php?id={abdid} but,

replace *{abdid}* with a value which is defined by me. for it.

Waiting for suggestions.

Comment: Okay it great that you want to do something, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, please re-think your question so that we can help you.

Comment: I am asking , how can i detect value {abdid} in URL and replace the same with , suppose *a5df4a6d4f6as4df4af45daf* this

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What @TejashwiKalpTaru is trying to tell you, is that Stackoverflow isn't a place where people create your code for free. It is expected that you tried to solve the problem yourself first, and you show what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$value = 'value_defined_by_me';
$url = 'https://abc.amindfad.com/c.php?id={abdid}';
$url = str_replace('{abdid}', $value, $url); //output: https://abc.amindfad.com/c.php?id=value_defined_by_me
```

Answer (score 0):

As in simple

```
let url = new URL('https://abc.amindfad.com/c.php?id=value&name=john');

let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);

console.log(searchParams.get('id'));  // outputs "value"

console.log(searchParams.get('name'));  // outputs "john"
```